# Swift filter with condition

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a filter to filter an Array of vehicles. I'm filtering according to price, performance and, optionally, to gearing type.

```
func filterCarSpecifications(among carSpecifications: [CarSpecification]) -> [CarSpecification] {

    let filteredCars = carSpecifications.filter {

        let performance = $0.car.ps ?? 0.0

        return $0.pricing.price >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPrice.rounded(.down)
            && $0.pricing.price <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPrice.rounded(.up)
            && performance >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPerformance
            && performance <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPerformance
    }

    if IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision {
        return filteredCars.filter {
            let transmission: GearingType = .automatic
            return $0.car.gearingType == transmission
        }
    }

    return filteredCars
}
```

`IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision` is a Bool to check if the user wants to see only automatic vehicles. Is there a way to include this extra value into my original filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append

```
&& IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision ? $0.car.gearingType == .automatic : true
```

to your initial conditions

Comment: Could you briefly explain how the logic works? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `condition ? true : false` is equivalent to `if condition { true } else { false }`. Hope you clear with the solution.

Comment: Got it! I'm used to use it on assignments, but seeing it as part of a condition doesn't look as straightforward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
func filterCarSpecifications(among carSpecifications: [CarSpecification]) -> [CarSpecification] {

    let filteredCars = carSpecifications.filter {

        let performance = $0.car.ps ?? 0.0

        return $0.pricing.price >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPrice.rounded(.down)
            && $0.pricing.price <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPrice.rounded(.up)
            && performance >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPerformance
            && performance <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPerformance
            && (!IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision || $0.car.gearingType == .automatic)
    }

    return filteredCars
}
```

When `IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision == false`, the left hand side of `||` operator becomes true, so the right hand side is ignored.

When it is `true`, `!IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision` becomes `false`. You know `false || someBoolValue` is equivalent to `someBoolValue`.

So, `$0.car.gearingType == .automatic` is evaluated only if `IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision == true`.

Answer (score 1):

Append it like this

```
func filterCarSpecifications(among carSpecifications: [CarSpecification]) -> [CarSpecification] {

let filteredCars = carSpecifications.filter {

    let performance = $0.car.ps ?? 0.0

    return $0.pricing.price >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPrice.rounded(.down)
        && $0.pricing.price <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPrice.rounded(.up)
        && performance >= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMinPerformance
        && performance <= IoC.filterDataService.selectedMaxPerformance 
        && (IoC.filterDataService.autoTransmision) ? $0.car.gearingType == transmission : true
  }
}
```